# Triger update function when column updates in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.4

I have users table with columns status_id (int), additional_status(int) and status_changed(DATE).

I want to autoupdate status_changed field every time when status_id or additional_status changes.

Here is what I have by now:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_status_changed()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.status_changed := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

  RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_update_status_changed
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF status_id, additional_status ON users
FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_status_changed();
```

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. When I change my status_id from phpPgAdmin - status_changed stays NULL. What am I'm missing?, help pls.

Comment: You need an `BEFORE` trigger. You can't change data in an `after` trigger

Comment: works! thanks!
answer, i'll accept

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is only notified if you @-reply. Like I just did.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter vote up in comment is not sent?

Comment: @ProstoTrader: Only for posts (questions and answers).